# Sign-up banner is displayed over the header

Tags: bug, status-norepro, design

There is a z-index issue (`z-index: 5001`) which brings to the front  top (over header) the sign-up bar when scrolling.

See this screenshot: [image: stackoverflow-signup-glitch]

Comment: There is so much going on in your screenshot I don't really know were to look. Can you add some freehand green circles to point me to the place I need to look?

Comment: what do you mean **green** circles? monster.

Comment: I can't reproduce this problem. If you can provide some additional details that would be great.

Comment: @JoeFriend: I can repro this on Chrome. Steps: 1) Open SO in an Incognito window. 2) Go to a question page. 3) Close the "this site uses cookies" banner at the bottom, revealing the blue sign-up banner under it. 4) Close the blue sign-up banner at the bottom of the window, causing the black sign-up banner at the top to appear. 5) Scroll down slightly so that the sticky top bar overlaps the sign-up banner. (And yeah, wow, that's a lot of banners...)

Comment: (Also, it seems that clicking the X on the black sign-up banner does nothing. That's presumably a different bug.)

Comment: Anyway, the problematic CSS rule seems to be `.s-hero--container { z-index: 5001 }`. Disabling that rule in the dev console makes the content of the sign-up banner stay under the top bar like it should.

Comment: @IlmariKaronen Thanks for the repro steps. We will get this fixed.

Comment: I agree with @IlmariKaronen that's a lot of banners. It might be easier to display all banners in a single place one-by-one (with probably legal cookie stuff first). Maybe a kind of "snackbar"...
Btw I didn't understand the purpose of sign-up banner since you have the "same" sign-up button 10px upper.